# Crear variable que se pueda pasar de un Windows Form a otro y devolverlo al Form principal

Tags: c#, windows-forms, variables

Buen dia,

Estoy trabajando como Windows Forms y controles de usuarios dentro de C#, el cual estoy trabajando con una aplicación que actúa como un reloj checador.

Esta primer pantalla actúa, como la pantalla principal. El cual todos los usuarios tiene acceso hasta este momento.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al presionar el menú "Usuario" abre un nuevo Form porque los siguientes módulos solo pueden entrar los "super-usuarios". La pantalla que se despliega es la siguiente. El cual actúa como un login.

Lo que pretendo hacer es que al momento de loguearse de forma correcta se mantenga una sesión, hasta presionar otro boton para que pueda finalizarse.

Lo que intente hacer es pasar una variable de un Form a otro con el siguiente codigo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí es el Form Principal:

`bool presionar = true;`

```
    private void usuarioToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

              if(presionar== true) { 
                Login login = new Login(presionar);
                login.ShowDialog();

                // Si el login es correcto, procedo con la apetura normal de la aplicacion
                if (login.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
                {

                }

                }
 else
                    {

                    }
               }
```

Este es el Login:

```
public partial class Login : Form
    {
        public Login( bool presionar)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.presionar2 = presionar;

        }
        bool presionar2;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox2.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Debes llenar todos los campos");
            }
            else
            {
                if (textBox1.Text == "Administrador" && textBox2.Text == "Admin")
                {
                    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;

                    MessageBox.Show("Datos Correctos");
                    this.Close();
                    presionar2 = false;
                }
                else
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("Datos incorrectos");
                    textBox1.Clear();
                    textBox2.Clear();
                }

            }
        }
```

Hasta aquí la variable presionar indica si el boton esta en "true o false" la variable si pasa hasta el momento del "Form Principal" al "Form Login" pero como regreso el valor de la variable presionar del "Form Login" al "Form Principal" osea viceversa.

Comment: Creas una clase global donde tenga la propiedad bool presionar;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agregas una nueva clase a tu proyecto que tenga las propiedades del usuario de esta manera:

```
public class Usuario
{
    public static string USERNAME;
    public static string PASSWORD;
    public static string FORMULARIO;
    public static bool PRESIONAR;
}
```

Le seteas los valores y accedes a ellos en cualquier momento mientras el programa se este ejecutando. Solo debes hacer referencia a la clase y listo.

Comment: ¡Excelente Bro, días buscando la solucion y al fin pude !

Comment: De nada hermano éxitos con tu proyecto.